# Flask exception "View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function"

Tags: python, flask

I'm following this book called: "Flask web development".

When I'm creating the login system he creates then I can an exception at my registration of the blueprint I have made.

Log:

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/Bo/Google Drev/Privat/HobbyProjekter/Event/manage.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bo/Google Drev/Privat/HobbyProjekter/Event/manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "C:\Users\Bo\Google Drev\Privat\HobbyProjekter\Event\app\__init__.py", line 42, in create_app
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 889, in register_blueprint
    blueprint.register(self, options, first_registration)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 153, in register
    deferred(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 172, in <lambda>
    s.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, view_func, **options))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\blueprints.py", line 76, in add_url_rule
    view_func, defaults=defaults, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 984, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: auth.login
```

The code for where I register my blueprint looks like this:

```
from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')
```

And that code imports from my auth__init__.py :

```
from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

from . import views
from flask import render_template
from . import auth

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

At last my view I'm trying to register (just a snippet):

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 endpoints called '/login'.  Change one of their names. Also the functions can't have the same names either.

Comment: That was a little imbarassing but this really helped! Thanks :)